# Centering CSS background-image with preceeding elements?

Tags: html, css, button, html-table, background-image

http://jsfiddle.net/ksHuz/

I'm trying to use a background-image with the `<a>` element in this fiddle, but the image only center aligns with text in IE. How do I center align the image in all browsers?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <select>
               <option>1</option>
                              <option>33</option>
                              <option>c</option>
                              <option>a</option>
                              <option>aaef</option>
            </select> 
            text
            <a href="#"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{
 background-image: url(http://stefankendall.com/files/excel.png);   
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in your example. Checked in Chrome and IE6.

Comment: Maybe specify a `background-position`?

Comment: The image is top-aligned in chrome and middle-aligned in IE.

Comment: I tried various background-positions, but they didn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Are you talking about (vertical?) alignment of the background image within the anchor, or the alignment of the anchor relative to the `text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the css for the anchor element will center it for standards-based browsers.  You might have to use some hack like those found on this page to get it to work in IE6 and IE7: http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

**Edit:** Come to think of it, you should probably use an actual image, in which case you could use `a img { vertical-align: middle; }` for the same effect (and it should work cross-browser, since img is already inline-block). Background images should ideally be used only for ornamentation, and a button is actual content.  For example, what if someone doesn't have css enabled? Image tags allow `alt` attributes, too, for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-think the approach. Your background image is rendering fine inside the `<a>` but this element is separate from text inside the `<td>`.

Depending what exactly you're trying to achieve, you could put the text and the link inside a `<span>` for example, or put the text inside the `<a>` and style it to not look like a link. You can also position the two on top of each other using positioning and/or floats.